# How to let MySQL (mysqld) to create and write to "/var/run/mysqld" directory?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, mysql

I really don't understand how all those privileges work in Linuxes.

To start MySQL server `mysqld` program has to write its `.pid` files to `/var/run/mysqld/` directory. But we know from [FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.13.html) that:

> Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process.

So `mysqld` ***has to*** create `/mysqld` directory under `/var/run/` ***every time*** MySQL server is started.

The owner and group of `/var` is `root` and `/var` is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 may 20 23:41 var.
```

And we also know from FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) that:

> /var/run should be unwritable for unprivileged users (root or users running daemons); it is a major security problem if any user can write in this directory.

So `mysqld` cannot write to the directory. Indeed when I run `mysqld` to start MySQL server I always get an error:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo mysqld --console
130720 23:43:02 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
130720 23:43:02 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
130720 23:43:02 [ERROR] Aborting
```

The question is: how `mysqld` can write `.pid` files to `/var/run/mysqld/` if standard forbids to open this directory for writing? This is a clear contradiction, isn't it?

My question is: how to let `mysqld` to create and write its files to `/var/run/mysqld/` without changing permissions of the `/var/run` directory? For now I see the only way:

```
user@user-desktop:$ sudo chmod a+w /var
```

But it is forbidden by the Standard.

Comment: Did you install `mysql-server` or something else?

Answer (score 4):

**/var/run should be unwritable for unprivileged users** means that root and sudo accounts (as these are privileged users) are allowed to write to it.

The upstart script for MySQL is started as root and then is allowed to create a file or directory in `/var/run`. And this file is created with the permission as set in the configuration. This should be `/etc/my.cnf` and it will have [something like this](http://www.networkredux.com/answers/view/Dev_and_Distros/Servers_and_Services/84):

```
[mysqld]
user   = mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

---

You should have something related to mysql in `/etc/init.d` After I installed MySQL Server I get this:

[image]

Are you sure you did not install the MySQL Client?

Comment: What is "upstart script for MySQL"? Is it `mysqld`? Unfortunately `mysqld` cannot create directories under `/var/run/` on my system automaticly. I don't know why. Where may I configure `mysqld` settings?

Comment: - yes mysqld. It is in /etc/init.d - it uses /etc/my.cnf (default that is) for settings and permissions.

Comment: For some reason I don't have `mysqld` in `/etc/init.d/`. It is in `/usr/sbin/mysqld`. I followed this post http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-952230-start-0.html and just changed `socket` and `pid-file` paths in `/etc/my.cnf` to different directory. Now all works fine. However I don't know if this is a right way. Nevertheless, thank you for your attention.

Comment: see update @green you must be doing something wrong ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind can you please help me with http://serverfault.com/questions/584886/how-to-configure-mysql-pid-file-permissions

Answer (score 3):

(Server version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 (Ubuntu) in WSL2)

Apparmor holds system binaries controlling permissions for other files. Before first succesful connect to mysqld server I added this line under 
" Allow pid, socket, socket lock file access", I removed it after and could 
still connect a second time.

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

```
/run/mysqld/*, rwx
```

```
~$ sudo service apparmor reload
```

Before this I had some other errors...had to change ownership and permission of /mysqld-files/ folder which was automatically created at install. Then add this option to config file which is set to to null by default which means server disables import and export ops.:

```
~$ sudo chown <username> /var/lib/mysql-files/ && chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql-files/
~$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

```
secure_file_priv = /var/lib/mysql-files
```

Also I had to add this because error then told me to:

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = ON
```

In WSL you don't have to initialize mysql. Happens at install (init content in /var/lib/mysql/). So we can login directly. "ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" if I don't write sudo at beginning of login command:

```
~$ sudo service mysql start
~$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter Password: [just ENTER]
```

Then finally fixing " No directory, logging in with HOME=/ ":

```
~$ sudo service mysql stop
~$ sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
```

p.s. Always make a copy before editing a config file, and change std port 3306, and [search through the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html).

Comment: If I `service mysql status` when rebooting on `wsl2`, I get `[info] MariaDB is stopped..`. So mysql is not initialized. Do I need `sudo` to start the service? With `sudo service mysql start` I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: By initialising I meant initialising the MariaDB data directory and creating the system tables in the mysql database, if they do not exist. Check the ownership of your MariaDB data directory, it should match the user running the command to run mysql. Here are some useful links for debugging https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_install_db/ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/